# Add brackets inside brackets automatically TeXstudio

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

I want to know if there's a way to automatically add brackets in all title parameters in a bib file using TeXstudio. For example, I have a bunch of these:

`title = {DEBOHID: A differential evolution based oversampling approach for highly imbalanced datasets}`

And I want to change it to:

`title = {{DEBOHID: A differential evolution based oversampling approach for highly imbalanced datasets}}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it doing some research in regular expressions used in TeXstudio. For whatever it's worth here it is:

You need to Find: `title=(\{[^{}]*\})`

and Replace with: `title={\1}`

Comment: Just observe that, in the example code from your question, there are spaces around the equal sign.

Comment: Yeah, I had some trouble with that too xD Thanks for the noticing it!